# C# Update data on Access DB won't work

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm trying to update some Data in my Windows form project on VS2013 and with an Access DB.
The following code won't work (the connecString is working as I can use it to insert and delete)

Help me please

```
    public static void alterLabelFromId(string id,string label,string table)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connecString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {

                cmd.CommandText = (@"UPDATE " + table + " SET Label = @label WHERE Id = @ID;");
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@label", label);


                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not working as in? Are there records in table with id you are sending to the query?

Comment: @danish Yes, I dynamicly get them while loading the list, I verified by debugging and it's the right Id...

Comment: Is this part `WHERE Id = @ID;` correct or maybe it should be `WHERE ID = @ID;`?

Comment: The column's name in the DB is Id so I guess it's okay

Answer (score 0):

Found it...
I just switched

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@label", label);
```

to

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@label", label);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
```